# laravel sanctum returns "unauthorized" while trying to logout other than dashboard

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have developed a laravel-vuejs app, implememted sanctum auth system here. While I attempt to logout from my dashboard It works nicely, but while I am attempting logout from landing page, it returns "401 unauthorized" status.

[image]

I am sharing my logout function here:

```
logout() {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${this.token}`
        axios.post('/api/logout').then(response => {
           localStorage.removeItem('token')
           localStorage.removeItem('userInfo')
           this.$router.push('/login')
        }).catch(errors => {
            console.log(errors.response.data)
        })
    }
```

Code from my api.php

```
Route::post('/logout','App\Http\Controllers\Authentication@logout')- 
>middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

from router.js

```
const routes = [
{
    path : '/',
    name : 'home',
    component : home,
    meta : { layout: website }
},
]

var router = createRouter({
    history : createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
    routes
})

function loggedIn() {
    return localStorage.getItem('token')
}

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
       if(!loggedIn()) {
           next({
               name : 'login'
           })
       }else{
           next()
       }
    }else if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.isVisitor)) {
        if(loggedIn()) {
             next({
                 name : 'dashboard'
             })
        }else{
            next()
        }
     }else{
       next()
    }
})
```

Comment: did you checked header in request? (failed request in landing page), check if you're sending it correctly.

Comment: uh thanks brother, I forgot to call token